# jQuery ajax loop and iteration scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm wondering why in the code below the **i** variable **still shows "5"** instead of showing **"1"** then **"2"** then **"3"** and so on ? Must be a scope issue but I don't really get it as I changed the scope of i variable in global and dom scope and still getting the same problem.
When I alert **i** outside the ajax function, it works well.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
   $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        method:'post',
        data: {
            html: 'Ajax data'
        },
        success: function (resp) {
            $('#success').append(i) // always 5
        }
    })
    $('#outsideAjax').append(i); // is okay
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQncd/)

**EDIT :**

I went for *@Tushar Gupta* solution as it best suits my needs but I get another issue, the iteration won't work if I set this option : ***processData: false***

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5G2wK/2/)

Why is this not working ?

Comment: Iterate is complete and `i` is 5 when it reaches the `success` callback of the first and subsequent AJAX requests.

Comment: read about closures in JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6RfRp/)</kbd>

```
var i = 0;

function ajax_call() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            html: 'Ajax data'
        },
        success: function (resp) {
            $('#success').append(i++);
            if (i < 5) {
                ajax_call();
            }
        }
    });
    $('#outsideAjax').append(i);
};
ajax_call();
```

Comment: Best solution imo, the other codes are displaying numbers randomly. Thank you !

Comment: @tcj this solution does not make parallel calls. It waits for each response to come back and then makes the next call. If that's what you need, then this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to Closures in JavaScript. Here's the fix -

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
   (function(i){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        method:'post',
        data: {
            html: 'Ajax data'
        },
        success: function (resp) {
            $('#success').append(i) 
        }
    })
    })(i);

    $('#outsideAjax').append(i); 
}
```

Comment: @tcj There is no guaranty you get sequence `012345` see --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/6RfRp/1/

Comment: @Tushar Gupta, you're right, I've tested other functions but only yours appears to render the numbers in the order, thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

you can fix this using closures, wrapping the value of i:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
   (function(val){
      $.ajax({
          url: '/echo/html/',
          method:'post',
           data: {
               html: 'Ajax data'
           },
           success: function (resp) {
               $('#success').append(val);
           }
       })
       $('#outsideAjax').append(val); // is okay
     })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using [`Function#bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):
http://jsfiddle.net/RQncd/1/

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
  $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    method:'post',
    data: {
      html: 'Ajax data'
    },
    success: (function (i, resp) {
      $('#success').append(i);
    }).bind(null, i)
  });
  $('#outsideAjax').append(i);
}
```

Comment: Or using a closure for the `$.ajax`

Comment: @Vega I agree but I prefer `bind()` :-)

Comment: Thanks, what is the best method, the one @Shreyas wrote or yours ? I mean, cross-browser compatibility wise.

Comment: @tcj If you target IE8 without polyfills, I would go with Shreyas code, otherwise mine!